# How can I pull in data from an Excel database to my HTML form as a list?

Tags: php, excel

I am creating a database with different user ID's in Excel. I want to take these user IDs in a HTML form and create a list. This has to be dynamic because with the help of a php script I am able to add new values to the "user ID" column in the excel sheet.

Can anybody suggest what I should do?

Comment: Is the excel file (not database)  in `.csv` or `.xlsx` format?

Comment: It is .xlsx format.

Comment: Then you will need to use the the [phpspreadsheet library](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: But this is really a job for a real Database like MySQL/mariaDB/SQLServer not a spreadsheet

Comment: Thankyou for your inputs! I had one more question : Incase if we have a .csv file then what do we have to do?